# Using JobIntentService (different class, with shared JobId)

Tags: android, jobservice

I wanna use JobIntentService for treating background works sequentially.

Even though I define Background works as 2 different classes (A.java, B.java),
I wanna these 2 classes works sequentially, 
So I decide to use same JobId for above 2 classes.

Is there any problem/restriction of using same JobId for different components?
Thanks for any response.

Comment: Did you ever find out if this strategy is ok? I'm asking myself the same question.